# export data to xls file format

Tags: python, json, excel, export

I have a text file with data of 6000 records in this format

```
{"id":"1001","user":"AB1001","first_name":"David  ","name":"Shai","amount":"100","email":"me@no.mail","phone":"9999444"}

{"id":"1002","user":"AB1002","first_name":"jone  ","name":"Miraai","amount":"500","email":"some1@no.mail","phone":"98894004"}
```

I want to export all data to excel file as shown bellow example

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to aid you. Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you use pandas?

Comment: I tired to import to excel directly , and tried to convert the text file to json and import excel , copy paste directly to excel

but  when I do like that all data are in single cell

Comment: Open the file;make a json object from the first line (`json.loads(next(file))`) and extract the keys; create a `csv.dictwriter` using those keys; write the first row; continue iterating over the file making a json object from each line and writing that object with the `dictwriter`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading in the text file, then converting to a dictionary with `json`, and using `pandas` to save a .csv file that can be opened with excel.

In the example below, I copied your text into a text file, called "myfile.txt", and I saved the data as "myfile2.csv".

```
import pandas as pd
import json 

# read lines of text file
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    lines=f.readlines()

# remove empty lines
lines2 = [line for line in lines if not(line == "\n")]

# convert to dictionaries
dicts = [json.loads(line) for line in lines2]  

# save to .csv
pd.DataFrame(dicts ).to_csv("myfile2.csv", index = False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use VBA and a json-parser

Your two lines are not a valid JSON.  However, it is easy to convert it to a valid JSON as shown in the code below. Then it is a relatively simple matter to parse it and write it to a worksheet.

The code assumes no blank lines in your text file, but it is easy to fix if that is not the case.

Using your data on two separate lines in a windows text file (if not windows, you may have to change the replacement of the newline token with a comma depending on what the generating system uses for newline.

I used the [JSON Converter by Tim Hall](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)

```
'Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime or
'    use late binding
Option Explicit
Sub parseData()
    Dim JSON As Object
    Dim strJSON As String
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject, TS As TextStream
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

    Dim vRes As Variant, v As Variant, O As Object
    Dim wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range

Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile("D:\Users\Ron\Desktop\New Text Document.txt", ForReading, False, TristateUseDefault)

'Convert to valid JSON
strJSON = "[" & TS.ReadAll & "]"
strJSON = Replace(strJSON, vbLf, ",")

Set JSON = parsejson(strJSON)

ReDim vRes(0 To JSON.Count, 1 To JSON(1).Count)

'Header row
J = 0
For Each v In JSON(1).Keys
    J = J + 1
    vRes(0, J) = v
Next v

'populate the data
I = 0
For Each O In JSON
    I = I + 1
    J = 0
    For Each v In O.Keys
        J = J + 1
        vRes(I, J) = O(v)
    Next v
Next O

'write to a worksheet
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet6")
Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .Style = "Output"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

**Results from your posted data**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [pandas](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/bitbucket.org/hrojas/learn-pandas/raw/master/lessons/03%20-%20Lesson.ipynb) module in conjunction with the [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function:

```py
import pandas as pd
with open('textfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[eval(i) for i in data])
df.to_excel('filename.xlsx', index=False)
```